# JavaScript Malware Scanning Detected BitCoin Mining on flatmap-stream v0.1.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, continuous-integration, virus-scanning

Not sure if this is related to this forum, please try to assist.

I have a website running in production. The customer run a virus scanning using  [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/) and found a Virus on flatmap-stream NodeJS module which is a dependent of nodemon@1.18.4 
https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=flatmap
https://www.npmjs.com/package/flatmap-stream

[image]

The customer detected the Virus when using the VirusTotal [Upload File](https://www.virustotal.com/#/home/upload) (Single file).

Since there are thousands of files that potentially contain a virus, what is the best way I can scan the entire project?

I am looking for a way to scan all of the local files before deploying to production, so can be inserted into a CI/CD pipeline